# Python Type Error While Writing a json File

Tags: python, json, unicode

I am making a dictionary of us metropolitan areas. Structure is like this:

```
  {
  "Abilene": {
    "allCities": [
      "Abilene"
    ], 
    "latitude": "30.1588129", 
    "longName": "Abilene, TX Metropolitan Statistical Area", 
    "longitude": "-85.6602058", 
    "primaryState": "TX", 
    "states": [
      "TX"
    ]
  },
```

I want to write this dictionary to a file as json encoded in unicode, so I imported unicode literals and the io package:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import io
from os.path import exists
import json
import unicodedata
```

I am setting keys in literals and values in unicode strings.

```
metropolitans[primaryCity] = {'allCities':allCities, 'longName':longName, 'allStates':states, 'primaryState':states[0]}

metropolitans[primaryCity]['longitude'] = unicode(str(coordinates[primaryCity]['longitude']), encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Then, I want to save metropolitans to a json file in unicode.

```
with io.open('results.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as results:
results.truncate()
json.dump(metropolitans, results, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf-8', results, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```

And, I get this error:

```
File "readMetropolitan.py", line 190, in <module>
json.dump(metropolitans, results, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 190, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str
```

Why is that? I know that I can complete writing a file with 'wb' but I want to write this file in unicode.

I can write this file if I use dumps() and write():

```
s = json.dumps(metropolitans, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf-8', indent=2, sort_keys=True)
results.write(s)
```

Comment: could you provide all your code?

Comment: I don't think you need the `encoding='utf-8'` in the `with io.open(...)`.

Comment: Where is the data such as `longName` coming from.  Is it unicode?

Comment: @Stephen Rauch I have a hard coded dictionary, which consists of literal values therefore unicode with from __future__ import unicode_literals. I think. And, I checked by type(longName).

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted above the error code hasn't even been ran since the error traceback said the error occurred when running this line at line 190 in file readMetropolitan.py:

```
json.dump(metropolitans, results, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```

While the code you posted was:

```
json.dump(metropolitans, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf-8', results, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```

They are definitely not the same. Perhaps the code was ran before the edit was made?

The first two lines of the error traceback specifically stated what triggered the error.

```
File "readMetropolitan.py", line 190, in <module>
json.dump(metropolitans, results, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 190, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str
```

Plus, you cannot have a positional argument `results` after keyword arguments. Therefore, it should instead be:

```
json.dump(metropolitans, results, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf-8', indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```